# Unable to publish InfoPath form to SharePoint due to large record volume

Tags: infopath, list-form

I'm hoping to sanity check something our SharePoint developer has been telling me as they work on updates to a request system we're running in InfoPath. They claim that due to the large record count in that request system (~20k records in the list) they get an error (sorry I have no specifics on what the error says) when they attempt to publish updates to the form.

Is that a thing?

I've done some InfoPath development at a previous company, but we had maybe a couple hundred records in that list when I left (not to mention that was over 5 yrs ago) so while I've never had the issue, I can't be sure it's not an actual limitation.

Also, we are working on migrating to Nintex. The concern here is that with this "error" we have no ability to rollback should we need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is not a thing. The number of list items does not affect whether you can publish an InfoPath form or not.

However, perhaps, the Client has a different kind of issue. For example, it is possible that an InfoPath form can stop working in large lists. For example, if an InfoPath form tries to retrieve too many list items when it loads or when a button is clicked. In this case, I can recommend archiving some list items or updating the InfoPath form's logic to stop retrieving too many list items.